# How to push a GitHub branch to server

Tags: git, github, version-control, subdomain, push

On my project I created a new branch called `dev` and want to push that branch to server but it seems to keep pushing the master branch.

**GitHub:**

- Two GitHub branches: Master and Dev

**On the server:**

- I have a production site: example.com
- and a staging site: dev.example.com

**My workflow:**

1. I work locally then push to GitHub Dev
2. Then push to Staging site: dev.example.com so I can test live
3. Once testing is done I merge Dev to Master and push Master to Production.

Thats what I want to do.

I'm currently stuck pushing the Dev branch to the Staging server: dev.example.com

**Here is my local git config file:**

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[branch "origin"]
    remote = git@github.com:xxxx/xxxxxxxx.git
    merge = refs/heads/master

[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:daugaard47/povertyresolutions.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master

[remote "production"]
    url = ssh://root@140.xx.xx.xx/var/repo/site.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/production/*

[remote "staging"]
    url = ssh://root@140.xx.xx.xx/var/repo/dev.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/dev/*

[branch "dev"]
    remote = staging
    merge = refs/heads/dev
```

Over on my server I have a repo directory: with `dev.git` & `site.git`

After I push to my `Dev Branch` I run `git push staging` to push to my dev.example.com, but it seems to push my `Git Master` branch instead.

This is what is in my `dev.git/hooks/post-receive` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/dev --git-dir=/var/repo/dev.git checkout -f
```

This is in my `site.git/hooks/post-receive` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/laravel --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but try the next line, and if it works, i'll add it as an answer:
`git push --progress --porcelain staging refs/heads/dev:dev`
Also make sure 1- your commit is in the log (`git log`)
2- your push isn't being rejected

Comment: @mgershen Hmm.. That didn't work: just got the following message `=       refs/heads/dev:refs/heads/dev   [up to date]
Done` ..... Maybe I'm looking at this wrong. On server side should I ssh into my `dev directory` and then `PULL` from the dev branch. New to this and a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

Let me recommend the following [branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchltnamegtremote) configuration:

```
git config branch.master.remote production
git config branch.dev.remote staging
```

and the following [remote refspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-remoteltnamegtpush) config:

```
git config remote.production.push refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/production/master
git config remote.staging.push refs/heads/dev:refs/remotes/staging/dev
```

On the server side I recommend to check in the hooks what remotes are being updated; `post-receive` hook [is fed with the list on the standard input](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#pre-receive) so add the check to your hooks:

```
while read old_hash new_hash ref; do
    if [ "$ref" = refs/heads/master ]; then
        git … checkout …
    fi
done
```

Comment: I am a little confused by your configuration as to what goes where based on my code above... So I have `1 git repo` and I want to keep master the same until I'm ready to push to production.... Once I change some code I want to send it to my `dev branch` on the git repo. Then I want to `push` that `new code / dev branch` to my live testing server with the `push staging` command. This needs to go to the `dev folder` on my live server. Once all is good, I will merge dev to master in my repo, and then push master to production. Is this possible?

Comment: The only way I could get it to work was to merge dev branch to master and then run push staging master. This defeats my purpose of having a development branch if I can't test the code on a live server.

Comment: Hmm… I thought you already have all this — two remote repositories, testing and production, branch `dev` is pushed to testing, branch `master` to production.

Comment: All is working except for pushing dev branch to testing. Or in my case dev branch to staging (which is the dev folder on the server.) Is there something special I have to do to get the dev branch to push up to my testing server.

Comment: The same way you push to production. You should have a bare repository and a `post-receive` hook that checks out the pushed branch. You can have 2 separate repositories (production and staging) or one repository and a clever `post-receive` hook that checks out each branch into the corresponding directory. At the client you do `git push staging dev`. Or with my configuration above just `git push`.